# maple plot of Belyi function

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, maple

I would like to understand how to construct Figure 5 of the paper [Composition is a generalized symmetry](https://www.labri.fr/perso/zvonkin/Research/tesselations.pdf) by Alexander Zvonkin:

[image: Figure 5 of Zvonkin 2010]

The hypermap/dessin d'enfant of Figure 4 is
[image: Figure 5 of Zvonkin 2010]
while the Belyi function (1) is defined by
$$f(x) = \frac{50000}{27} \cdot \frac{x^6(x-1)^3(x+1)}{(x^2 + 4x - 1)^5}.$$

Now, I understand that the plot in Figure 5 is over the complex plane, and that squares (= "black vertices") represent points $x$ where $f(x) = 0$, while circles (= "white vertices") represent points $x$ where $f(x) = 1$. But how do you get Maple to produce this plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was informed offline that the correct incantation is:

```
> plots[rootlocus](-1/f(x), x, 0 .. 1);
```